# Angular Material2 mat-list-item-content position

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying the below to override angular material2 mat-list-item-content style based on list index.

Component HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFill>
    <mat-list dense class="mat-list">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let message of messages" class="{{message.float}}">
         <mat-label>{{message.text}}</mat-label>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

Component CSS

```
.left .mat-list-item-content {
  float: left;
}

.right .mat-list-item-content {
  float: right;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `<mat-label>` component doesn't exist.

Comment: @Edric I was going through some sample in material, thats where i found mat-label. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/input/input-demo.html

Comment: that's only meant to work with inputs, **not** lists.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the alignment of mat-list-item using **flex-box** `justify-content`

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item class="left" role="listitem">
   LEFT
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item class="right" role="listitem">
     Right
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Below is the style. Note that you should put this style in the root style ( /src/styles.css ) or this style will not work.

```
/* LEFT align */
.mat-list .mat-list-item.left .mat-list-item-content{
      justify-content: flex-start;
}

/* RIGHT align */
.mat-list .mat-list-item.right .mat-list-item-content{
      justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* If you will use matLine */

  /* LEFT align */
.mat-list .mat-list-item.left .mat-list-text>*{
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}
  /* RIGHT align */
.mat-list .mat-list-item.right .mat-list-text>*{
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

Please see this link for the live sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-answer-alignment-list?file=styles.css

Comment: There's no such component called `mat-label`

Comment: yep @Edric you are right. I read the documentation and there is no component called mat-label. The OP is using mat-label no idea why.

Comment: @Edric thanks for sharing about that. I have updated my post and stackblitz link for including the alignment for matLine.

Comment: doesn't work, angular style encapsulation prevents the style to be applied

Comment: @CristianTraìna Please see the live sample code that I have included and it works fine in my end.

Comment: @davecar21 it works because it's inside `styles.css`. But in a component stylesheet it wouldn't work

Comment: @CristianTraìna Yes, That's why I have noted that put the style in the root style ( /src/styles.css ) or it will not override the syle and will not work. Then just add a `class="left"` or `class="right"` to `<mat-list-item>` to implement the alignment.

Comment: @davecar21 if other readers are interested, they can also disable encapsulation with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and use the style inside the component :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna Oh I see, I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-list-base .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-content {
justify-content: left;
```

}

You can use above code for positioning list items. It works for me

Answer (score 1):

This solution helps me, you can try if you want.

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item disableRipple="true" class="nav-link"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     *ngFor="let link of links">

     <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">{{ link.name }}</div>

  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions above and they worked for mat-list-item but did not for mat-list-option.

What did work was simply using `text-align`.

```
// align all child content to right
mat-list-item, mat-list-option {
  text-align: right;
}

// align specific child element
mat-list-option span {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned an expression to the class attribute with `class="message.float"` but the class attribute does not understand expressions and interprets `message.float` as a class name (inspect your DOM).

You need to either use ngClass `[ngClass]="message.float"` or bind the expression `class="{{message.float}}"`

(You should be having the same problem with `message.text`.)

Comment: Yeah, my bad, it was typo, i'm using bind expression.